# empy arrays when scraping instagram post links

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I'm following along the guide here:
https://medium.com/swlh/tutorial-web-scraping-instagrams-most-precious-resource-corgis-235bf0389b0c

I've got it working in the past but for some reason now it's returing empty arrays like the following instead of the list of permalinks

```
C:\Users\19053\InstagramPublicImageDownloader\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/19053/InstagramPublicImageDownloader/getpermalinks.py
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Should look like

`['https://www.instagram.com/p/CDRbCxjBakW/','https://www.instagram.com/p/CDMQ9J2Fvl4/','...and so on']`

code as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

url = "https://www.instagram.com/dairyqueen/"
browser = Chrome()
browser.get(url)
post = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/'
post_links = []
while len(post_links) < 25:
    links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
    for link in links:
        if post in link and link not in post_links:
            post_links.append(link)
            scroll_down = "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"
            browser.execute_script(scroll_down)
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            print(post_links[:25])
```

Comment: Does the below answer has solved your issue? if yes, feel free to accept/upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

To collect the url you mean, use this css selector `div.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w > a`, and use `WebDriverWait` instead of `time.sleep(...)`.

You should placement scroll to bottom inside the loop block and repeat until number of elements as you expected.

Try following code:

```
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/dairyqueen/')

scroll_down = "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"

while True:
    links = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.v1Nh3.kIKUG._bz0w > a')))
    if(len(links) < 25):
        browser.execute_script(scroll_down)
    else:
        break

post_links = []
for link in links:
    post_links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
    
print(post_links[:25])
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```